# Characters not loading properly in excel when I open a CSV, how to fix that?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Let's say, I save a csv file from notepad/notepad++ with below text
Ákos Illés

[image: notepad++]

Then, after opening the same in excel sheet, it is showing as below.
Ãkos IllÃ©s

[image: excel application]

Can anyone please suggest how to load this csv in excel properly.

I tried the steps in this [link](https://support.youcanbook.me/article/502-how-can-i-get-excel-to-properly-display-special-characters-in-the-data-export), but it is converting the csv to excel(.xlsx) format, but we need it in csv only.

Answer (score 0):

The document encoding may be UTF8. Windows needs UTF8 with byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning, or it may not be able to detect the encoding. Alternatively, use the data import wizard and specify the encoding (CP 65001 UTF8)

Comment: That is mentioned in the link I provided in the question. But it converts to xlsx,not csv file.